# Is it possible to have a custom ROM with a locked bootloader?

Tags: security, rom-flashing, custom-roms, encryption, bootloader

I just mention in-advance to please correct me if I'm mistaken on anything, I've a limited tech proficiency.

I've a Samsung S9 (Android 10) and I wish to install an AOSP ROM (also on Android 10), but I researched and found my phone still uses "Full Disk Encryption" instead of "File Based Encryption" (which is a requirement by Google as of Android 10).

I think one must unlock the bootloader in order to install any custom ROM, right?

If yes, then I'm left with FDE encryption and unlocked bootloader.

FDE means if my phone is stolen (or taken by force) while turned ON (i.e., always in my case) my data is at risk, right?

Unlocked bootloader means someone tech savvy can have (some kind of a) backdoor access to my phone's data even if my phone is turned OFF, right?

So, logically, in order to be secure, one must either have a newer device that supports FBE, or an FDE one with locked bootloader (and also not have it taken while turned ON)

Thus, I thought maybe I can have a custom ROM installed but still have the bootloader locked after I install it?

Again, I apologize if I'm mistaken on anything, please do correct me. Thanks

Comment: https://www.samsungknox.com/en/secured-by-knox

Comment: https://copperhead.co/android/docs/devices

Comment: The requirements by Google only affect devices which are released new to the market. Devices that are upgraded aren't affected especially the FBE requirement because changing the encryption scheme without deleting all data is heavily complicated and I would assume was never implemented.

Comment: FDE mans your data is encrypted and an attacker still has to break your lock screen pattern/PIN/password. And if the encryption is hardware based (which should be true for the S9) the attack has to be performed on-device, not off-line on a high-end computer with GPU support and hundred-thousands of password tries per second.

Comment: @Robert Hi, thank you for your response. After reading this excellent article ( https://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2016/11/24/android-n-encryption/ ), here's a few relevant takeaways that made me post this thread.

" [...] encryption is an all-or-nothing proposition. Your machine is either on or off; accessible or inaccessible. As long as you make sure to have your laptop stolen only when it’s off, disk encryption will keep you perfectly safe."

Comment: @Robert Also: 
"[...] smartphone users are never encouraged to shut down their device. In practice this means that — after you enter a passcode once after boot — normal users spend their whole day walking around with all their cryptographic keys in RAM. Since phone batteries live for a day or more (a long time compared to laptops) encryption doesn’t really offer much to protect you against an attacker who gets their hands on your phone during this time."

Comment: @Robert And:
"users do lock their smartphones. In principle, a clever implementation could evict sensitive cryptographic keys from RAM when the device locks, then re-derive them the next time the user logs in. Unfortunately, Android doesn’t do this — for the very simple reason that Android users want their phones to actually work. Without cryptographic keys in RAM, an FDE system loses access to everything on the storage drive. In practice this turns it into a brick. For this reason, once you boot an Android FDE phone it will never evict its cryptographic keys from RAM. And this is not good."

Comment: The attack you describe is doable for PCs with removable RAM modules but on smartphones RAM is part of the central SoC where is also the CPU included. Accessing RAM inside an SoC while it is running is more a theoretical threat. I would assume that only a few intelligence agencies world wide may have the knowledge and the equipment to do so.

Comment: @Robert So from what I understand, you'd actually feel secure if your FDE encrypted Android phone was stolen, while turned ON yet locked, correct?